# how to do category based select query conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have as table like this

```
id  category  minLimit  maxLimit  count  
11  Bannana     100       200      50
12  Bannana     200       300      20  
13  Bannana     300       400      40  
14  Apple       100       200      60  
15  Apple       200       300      70
```

now i will execute a query a query  and return Bannana By limit 250 and Apple by limit 150.
in this case i can run q query like this:

```
select  
   * 
from main_table 
where 
   (category = 'Bannana' and minLimit <= 250 and maxLimit > 250) or 
   (category = 'Apple' and minLimit <= 150 and maxLimit > 150)
```

In another solution i can create an extra table insert my where clause conditions(Bannana 250, Apple 150) data and do a join with main_table. I want to know what is the most efficient solution?

Note : my where clause conditions (Bannana - 250, Apple 150) in real case is more than 5000 record

Comment: Your query returns nothing and what is the question?

Comment: @forpas thanks. i edited my query.  in this query my where clause consists two condition line. but in real case my query is more than 5000 line. i will know is there a better solution instead of many and-or

Comment: Maybe you could try with a table variable to store the conditions?

Comment: johey i know this. i can create an table, insert conditions on it and do a join. but i will know is there an more efficient way? maybe plsql has better ability for this

Comment: maybe with an array of values (Varray) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_arrays.htm

Comment: @DanielE. i dont know how many it can be efficent but i think it can be good idea. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a more efficient way to achieve what you ask than request the db do what it was built to do: join data. Insert 5000 records to another table and then do:

```
create table conditions_table(category VARCHAR(20), limit INT);
insert into conditions_table('Bannana', 250);
insert into conditions_table('Apple', 150);
```

Then:

```
select  
   * 
from 
  main_table m
  INNER JOIN 
  conditions_table c --could be temp table, real table, table var etc
  ON
   c.category = m.category and
   c.limit >= m.minLimit and
   c.limit < m.maxlimit
```